# Lp bounds of the Heat Kernel

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

These days, I am struggling with a problem which seems very straightforward (and I'm pretty sure it is straightforward) but it resists to my attempts to prove it. Here it is:

Let $\mathcal H_t$ be the heat kernel in $\mathbb R^d$:
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal H_t(x) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi t)^{d/2}} \exp{\left(-\frac{|x|^2}{4 \pi t}\right)}, \ \forall x \in \mathbb R^d.
\end{equation}
It is classical that we have the following formula for the $L^p$ norm of this guy, $1 < p < \infty$:
\begin{equation}
 \| \mathcal H_t \|_{L^p} = C_p t^{-\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)\frac{d}{2}}
\end{equation}
where $C_p$ is an universal constant.
In the paper [Mathematische Zeitschrift, 1984](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01174182?LI=true), T. Kato claims that from this identity, it is easy to deduce that if $1 < p \leq q < \infty$, then
\begin{equation}
 \| \mathcal H_t * u \|_{L^q} \leq c t^{-\left(\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{q}\right)\frac{d}{2}} \|u\|_{L^p}.
\end{equation}
Why is that last inequality true? Thanks for your explanations :)

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but could you let me know where I might find a proof of this classic reslut for the Heat Kernel norm? I'm finding it surprisingly hard to find online

Comment: Well this is actually quite a brutal estimate, using the explicit form of the heat kernel, the Gauss integral, and the expression of the convolution... I think it might be done in the Evans textbook :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing else than Youngs inequality on convolutions applied to the convolution $\mathcal H_t * u$. See [Young's Inequality on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_convolutions).

Comment: The link looks broken. There are [better ways](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16357) to insert  links, which avoid this problem.

Comment: Yes I know that Young's inequality is one of my only tools, but I really can't find the good combination of parameters to obtain the result...

Comment: I fixed the link.

Comment: @Dobby: Renaming the variables appropriately, Young's inequality says $\|\mathcal{H}_t \ast u\|_q \le \|u\|_p \|\mathcal{H}_t\|_r$ where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{q}+1$.  So what does $r$ have to be?

Comment: Sorry i was away for too long: So @Nate Eldredge: Thanks for fixing the link and for clarifying the details.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot @Nate, I got it, i knew that it was easy... I'm so dumb! So, with your renaming, fixing p and q yields
\begin{equation}
1-\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q},
\end{equation}
which gives exactly the expected result. THANKS!